# What are the best resources for latin and greek roots, suffixes and prefixes?

Tags: resources

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English

I found this page, but the problem is that it's on three pages, the other issue is that we search for the meaning instead of going through one by one and check the meaning of all of them all the time. Is there an online resources like RhymeZone, but for latin and greek roots, suffixes and prefixes? Or something better than the Wikipedia pages above?

Comment: Is this so you can fill out your -mancies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://www.oakton.edu/user/3/gherrera/Greek%20and%20Latin%20Roots%20in%20English/greek_and_latin_roots.pdf) pdf includes the most common Latin and Greek roots, stems and prefixes in English.

If you would like to dig deeper, you can consider purchasing (or borrowing) textbooks used for Classics studies that help students to learn Latin and Greek. For example, [Reading Greek: Text and Vocabulary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521698510) or [Wheelock's Latin 7th Edition (The Wheelock's Latin Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0061997226). These were the textbooks used by university, but there are other resources available depending on your level/use case.